# Connect to AWS managed Cassandra with Java client

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, cassandra

Has anyone been able to connect to AWS MCS using a java client? Following their docs I have supplied -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore and -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword to the JVM on my local machine but I just get the following error:

"Could not reach any contact point"

I am able to use the same details to connect via cqlsh. the AWS docs for the Java client seem a little light on detail.

The last thing I tried looked like this  :

```
InetSocketAddress address1 = new InetSocketAddress("cassandra.xx-xxxx-x.amazonaws.com", 9142);            

return CqlSession.builder()
                    .withLocalDatacenter("xx-xxxx-x")
                    .addContactPoint(address1)
                    .withAuthCredentials("amc_connection-at-xyz", "xxxxxxxxxx")
                    .withKeyspace("xxxxxxxx")
                    .build();
```

Suspect i need to supply an SslContext but not sure how to configure one for this, the actual exception thrown is DriverTimeoutException

Answer (score 0):

It appears you can add an SSL context by adding the following to your builder:

`.withSslContext(SSLContext.getDefault())`

As an example:

```
CqlSession.builder()
    .addContactPoints(contactPoints)
    .withSslContext(SSLContext.getDefault())
    .withLocalDatacenter("us-east-2")
    .withAuthProvider(new SigV4AuthProvider("us-east-2"))
    .build());
```

There appears to be a more detailed document here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mcs/latest/devguide/ManagedCassandraService.pdf

Specifically - page 16

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You would need to call withSSL() in order to use the system properties, https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/ssl/#driver-configuration.